# Geting the number of rows in doctrine query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

A have a code like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Publish p
         ORDER BY p.update_date DESC");

   $query->setFirstResult(($page-1)*$ads_on_page);
   $query->setMaxResults($ads_on_page);      
   $posts = $query->getResult();
```

Now I am trying to get the total number of rows in the query (not depending on setMeaResult course).
I tried to use count() function but it doesn works...

---

So I did `SELECT p, count(p.id) as p_count FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Publish p ORDER BY update_date DESC` and it works, but I see that now  I have only one row [I think that it because `count()` return only one row]. So I did two queries, like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Publish p
            ORDER BY p.update_date DESC");
   $query->setFirstResult(($page-1)*$posts_on_page);
   $query->setMaxResults($posts_on_page);

   $count_query = $em->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS p_count FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Publish p
            ORDER BY p.update_date DESC");


   $posts = $query->getResult();
   $count = $count_query->getResult();
```

It works well, but I would like to know is it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. The first query will get only the number of records up to the number that is set with `setMaxResults`. The second query will count how many records a query may return. There's no another way to do two different things.

PS: If you want to build pagination, consider using [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions). It will let you write a query only once (but it still does two queries underneath).

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2.2 includes a pagination class that should solve the problem: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

setMaxResults not working on OneToMany

Example use a subquery, join many linked entities, use setMaxResults...
You'll get a limit for the whole query...

So if you want 2 articles, you fetch all their comments. Using setMaxResults 2

You'll have the first article with 2 comments.

This feature is not smart to be polite.